# CSS - Too wide table in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i create my layout with flexbox and now i would like show table. But when a table has a lot of records, it doesn't add a scroll bar, it overflows the page. Does anyone know what to do about this? I have looked variously on the net and found this problem, however, nowhere have I found a completely reliable solution... For simplicity, I've simplified the example. Thank you

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <!-- Layout -->
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <!-- Layout -->
      <div style="display: flex;">
        <!-- Layout -->
        <div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Note</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Pepík zdenda z Brna</td>
              <td>245</td>
              <td>Sat Oct 10 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)</td>
              <td>Moc dlouha poznamka, ktera je fakt nesnesitelně dlouha</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

What i want:

[image]

Thank you very much

**Edit:**

What i have:

[image]

What i want:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `overflow-x: scroll;` and remember include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in head.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>

<div style="width:90%;" >
  <div style="display: flex;  overflow-x: scroll;">
    <!-- Layout -->
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <!-- Layout -->
      <div style="display: flex; ">
        <!-- Layout -->
        <div>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Note</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Note</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Note</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Pepík zdenda z Brna</td>
              <td>245</td>
              <td>Sat Oct 10 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)</td>
              <td>Moc dlouha poznamka, ktera je fakt nesnesitelně dlouha</td>
              <td>Pepík zdenda z Brna</td>
              <td>245</td>
              <td>Sat Oct 10 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)</td>
              <td>Moc dlouha poznamka, ktera je fakt nesnesitelně dlouha</td>
            <td>Pepík zdenda z Brna</td>
              <td>245</td>
              <td>Sat Oct 10 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)</td>
              <td>Moc dlouha poznamka, ktera je fakt nesnesitelně dlouha</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for response. This works because it's not in one div, but in body. However, my content is in x divs which are set as flex. And when I add it to the top parent div, I'm scrolling the entire content, which I don't want. I only want to scroll the table. Here's how I have it now:https://jsfiddle.net/luboshnedy/8pxzh0nb/15/ and how I need it: https://jsfiddle.net/luboshnedy/g5sjuw7L/3/

Answer (score 0):

> I have added `overflow-x: auto;` on the parent div of the table you can find more details about [table responsiveness here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table_responsive.asp) and added some styling to the table like padding, from my side it works.

```css
th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <!-- Layout -->
    <div style="display: flex;">
      <!-- Layout -->
      <div style="display: flex;">
        <!-- Layout -->
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Note</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Note</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>City</th>
              <th>Note</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Pepík zdenda z Brna</td>
              <td>245</td>
              <td>Sat Oct 10 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)</td>
              <td>Moc dlouha poznamka, ktera je fakt nesnesitelně dlouha</td>
              <td>Pepík zdenda z Brna</td>
              <td>245</td>
              <td>Sat Oct 10 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)</td>
              <td>Moc dlouha poznamka, ktera je fakt nesnesitelně dlouha</td>
            <td>Pepík zdenda z Brna</td>
              <td>245</td>
              <td>Sat Oct 10 1998 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)</td>
              <td>Moc dlouha poznamka, ktera je fakt nesnesitelně dlouha</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: u can see in this image]

[image: v2.0 image]

u can see in the code I have added more columns and it is working.

Comment: Did you try it? Because your example don't work. Result is still same, table isn't responseive.

Comment: u can refer to the image but to make it scroll big resolution I think you will need more columns

Comment: It depends upon the size of table and the screen width to make it scroll

Comment: It work here beacuse overflow is set on frame. Try go to "Full page" and change width, you will see it isn't working.

Comment: please check the above image is it what you need? or I cant understand it?

Comment: Your image has a scroll bar for the whole page. I only want the scroll bar for the table. I have completed my question and added a scrennshot where it is hopefully more clear.Thanks

Comment: Here's how I have it now:jsfiddle.net/luboshnedy/8pxzh0nb/15 and how I need it: jsfiddle.net/luboshnedy/g5sjuw7L/3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253972/discussion-between-u-33-and-petr-klekner).